# Rodapé de assinatura no final da pagina não pode quebrar

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tenho uma tabela  que é dinâmica e que ao final da tabela há uma `div` com assinatura e data do recebimento.

O que preciso é que essa `div` não quebre com a pagina como está ocorrendo na imagem.

É necessário que essa `div` vá para outra pagina por completo.

A Assinatura do recebedor teria que ir para outra pagina junto com a data do recebimento ou sempre ficar no rodapé de todas as paginas.

[[image: Imagem mostrando a tabela e a área de assinatura sendo separada em 2 paginas.]
<sup>clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XS9q.png)

Comment: Icaro você tentou usar um simples <br> para pular as linhas ou a tabela muda de tamanho ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar fazer isso com o [`break-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/break-after).

> ##### break-after
>
> A propriedade break-after do CSS configura como uma quebra de página, coluna ou região deve se comportar após renderizar um elemento. Se nenhum elemento foi renderizado, a propriedade é ignorada.
>
> ###### `break-after: page`
>
> Força uma quebra de página logo após a caixa principal.

Parece ter um bom suporte:

- [caniuse:`break-after`](https://caniuse.com/?search=break-after)
- [caniuse:`page-break-after`](https://caniuse.com/?search=page-break-after)

#### Exemplo de uso

```css
@media print {
  .break-page {
    break-after: page;
    page-break-after: always;
    /* para aumentar compatibilidade, já que ele foi renomeado para break-after */
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Page 1 </h1>

<div class='break-page'></div>

<h1>Page 2</h1>
```

A imagem abaixo mostra o resultado de uma impressão, utilizando o Google Chrome Versão 103.0.5060.114
[[image: Screenshot de visão da impressão utilizando o CSS break-after]
<sup>clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq4hk.png)